# Social Login redirect in Lightning

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-community

I'm trying to create a redirect to a relative url within my community from the login page. I've managed to successfully do so using normal login/registration methods, but am having trouble with social login/registration. I have read the documentation on startURL here: https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&type=5, but there is some ambiguity that, if cleared up, may help.

Using the standard Facebook and Google auth provider configurations, I have located the "Single Sign-On Initialization URL" parameter within the auth provider detail. It is, however, a generated output field that I cannot modify. This leads me to believe that the standard social login component I am using with Community Builder utilizes the url to navigate. Although I have been able to retrieve the source for the loginForm component and customize it, I have not been able to do so with the socialLogin componet.

My main questions are:

1. Can I achieve a redirect with the standard social login component via configuration only?
2. If not, can I customize the "Single Sign-On Initialization URL" that is generated in the auth provider detail?
3. If not, can I customize the socialLogin component?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell us more about the purpose of the redirect you're trying to create - is it to customize user experience based on some criteria (inbound source, customer type, etc)? If the length of the parameter string is less than 30 characters, I think I can help you.

Comment: I am redirecting to a custom application page I have created in the community depending on the login type, all I really need is the startUrl to accomplish this, which should be below 30 characters in this case.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that a public facing community has deep links and then when a user wishes to sign up or login in they should be taken back to the page where they clicked on the login/signup button.
No brainer.
Jalal, did you solve this?
If I find the answer I will respond here.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend an endpoint, including a redirect using the experience ID or [Expid URL parameter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_expid.htm&type=5) as it's also referred to. The best place I know of that will give you even more examples of how to use and implement it besides the section of the Salesforce Help I've already linked you to is the [Salesforce External Identity Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/). I recommend you search on Expid within that document as there are a number of ways to implement it.

It can be added to your redirect in a number of ways. I'd expect you to want to be able to handle the callback from the redirect at that endpoint. For that reason, I think you'll want to look at the section on [Embedded Login: Allow Visitors to Log In to Your Web Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_intro.htm) that covers client side and server side callbacks.